# Writing a method to sort a singly linkedlist in ascending order (java)

Tags: java, linked-list

the method 'insertAscending' only gives me the first number even after i enter new ones. can anyone help with what i'm doing wrong? Thanks.

public class LinkedList13 {
    // Private inner class Node

```
private class Node{
    int data;
    Node link;


    public Node(){
        data = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        link = null;
    }

    public Node(int x, Node p){
        data = x;
        link = p;
    }
}
// End of Node class

public Node head;

public LinkedList13(){
    head = null;
}

public void insertAscending(int data){

    Node node = new Node();
    node.data = data;

     if (head == null)
         head = node;
     Node p = head;

     while (p.link != null)
     {
         if (p.link.data > data)
         { node.link = p.link;
           p.link = node;
           break;
         }
         p= p.link;
     }



}
```

}

Comment: The while loop is never executed. After head is set to the first node, p.link == head.link == null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should return after setting the head of the list (when the first element is added).

Second of all, you should handle the case where the newly inserted node is the smallest in the list (and therefore should come first). Your loop never compares the added node to the head of the list.

Finally, if the added element wasn't inserted in the while loop, it should be inserted after the while loop.

```
public void insertAscending(int data)
{
    Node node = new Node();
    node.data = data;

    if (head == null) {
        head = node;
        return;
    } else if (node.data < head.data) {
        node.link = head;
        head = node;
        return;
    }
    Node p = head;

    boolean added=false;
    while (p.link != null)
    {
        if (p.link.data > data)
        { 
           node.link = p.link;
           p.link = node;
           added = true;
           break;
        }
        p = p.link;
    }
    if (!added) 
        p.link = node;
}
```

Comment: i really appreciate the explanation

Comment: 6 years later and this helped a lot. ty :)

Answer (score 3):

Hint: is (p.link != null) ever true?

Comment: isn't it true for the last node?

Comment: good point! I missed that ...  @Eternal Punishment, it is *false* for the last node. Think about what makes it `true` (where in your code would that happen?).

Comment: @EternalPunishment consider case where length of list == 1.

Answer (score 0):

Check out your `if` condition `if(p.link.data > data)` the only way a `node` gets into the list is when that is true. This means, that, if the value of `data` being inserted it greater than (or equal to) everything that's been inserted so far, it will be discarded.

An easy way to fix this is change `break` to `return` and add `p.link=node` at the end (after the loop).

Comment: should i add the p.link = node before or after p = p.link?

Comment: after the loop.
Also see the other answer about `p.link != null` always being false.
That's actually a bigger issue.